# Depth First Search example and detailed explanation

Tags: graph-theory

I need some clarification on how the depth first search algorithm works on a matrix.  It doesn't seem all the intuitive to me and the assignments seem quite arbitrary.  Can anyone perhaps explain it better to me by 1) providing a better way of selecting starting points and matches and 2) explain what "improving a match" is?  It seems to me that you're simply providing an alternative than improving anything.

Let's say we have this matrix here:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

The girls are listed on the rows and boys on columns.  So the initial match was (g2,b2); (g3,b3); (g4,b4).

Comment: Could you supply some more context? It seems like you are considering some special problem here, what is it? And I am guessing your matrix is an incidence matrix, is that correct?

Comment: We're using Hall's Marriage Algorithm here.  girls are listed on the rows and boys on the columns so when there's a match between girl 1 and boy 1 there would be a 1 on entry 1,1.

Comment: So you have a bipartite graph, consisting of the two vertex sets boys and girls. You want to find a maximal matching?

Comment: Yes, using the depth first search.  I would like to know a systematic approach of doing it.  My instructor makes it seem as if he was picking the matches out of thin air...

Comment: I am not sure which algorithm you are referring to. Is it the augmenting path algorithm?

Comment: No its the depth first search algorithm.

Comment: Depth-first is a quite general term. Could you be more specific, or even better, describe the algorithm?